# Tekkit pipes getting clogged

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-buildcraft

I have a Tekkit server running and I just started using a quarry. Twice now I have logged in and it has been SUPER laggy. I have discovered that this is because the pipes are getting clogged. After minutes of destroying my transport pipes, one I destroyed popped out this monster![image]

What could be causing this? Is there a known bug with pipes I haven't heard about? Maybe could it be because it is going into the earth and being surrounded on all sides? I do also have some powered gold pipes in this system, the rest being cobblestone

Comment: some chunks may not be loaded, double check the network doesn't go through a unloaded chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple reasons for buildcraft pipes to be "gummed up"

the main one being chunks in the pipe system unload. the solution would be use chunk loaders, or pipe into an ender chest/item tesseract.

another possible cause is that the pipes have nowhere to go, in build craft it will usually spit the item at the ground if it cannot find a destination, but sometimes if the network is elaborate it will indefinitely loop and clog the system.

I should also point out that gold pipes no longer need to be powered, by default they speed items up (but you need to use at least 2 to achieve speed. Powering them will slow items down, so this could be a cause as well. having many golden pipes powered will congest a system.

do NOT log out and leave the quarry running unless it is properly chunk loaded.

Comment: When I power a gold pipe it does in fact speed up. I am running Tekkit classic so maybe you're referring to Tekkit lite? The chunk unloading must be the cause because I do log out and this happens after long periods of logging out. So what can I do to keep the chunks loaded? I did a little research and found some items like World Anchor and such. Is that what I should use?

Comment: oh yeah, the gold pipe change was pretty recent so Classic doesn't have it. there are chunk loaders you can craft, (I'm pretty sure at least, I don't remember what tekkit classic has). You could also pump the items directly into an ender chest, that will prevent pipes from logging. That will raise the issue of your inventory room isn't loaded though, so the ender chest would probably clog up, but at least it wont lag.

A world anchor would do the trick, but it keeps a very very large area loaded, use a personal anchor or 2 instead.

Comment: I used ender chests and that is a great idea! Thank you. Works great

Answer (score 2):

No matter what tekkit your using they have Pneumatic tubes (spellings a little incorrect) Theses are lag free and deliver the items into the nearest inventory. If the inventory is full it will try and find another one. If there is no other route it will just keep bouncing in the pipe. This stops overflow and allows you to log out without causing to much lag.

Also if your using Tekkit lite there's applied energetics which have no lag at all. The movement delay is instant and its more powerful. i would google tutorials if you want to find more about that out.